# Спецификация USB классов для геймпада

Tags: linux, windows, usb, драйвер, avr

Делаю собственный геймпад на микроконтроллере AVR, необходимо написать USB драйвер для него, узнал что есть спецификации классов для стандартных классов устройств а где их найти и в чем они заключаются?

И еще хотелось бы узнать как подружить собственный геймпад с играми? я так понял нужно "эмулировать" собственный геймпад как геймпад Xbox или PS

Comment: Попробуйте посмотрите подклассы HID (Под HID попадают мышка клавиатруа... и геймпад скорее всего тоже).

Comment: http://www.usb.org/developers/docs/devclass_docs/

Comment: геймпады работают через hid драйвер, стандартный, одинаковый для всех. на старых ОС через evdev. Можно сразу эмулировать hid